# How can I get more sounds for my Roland D20?

Tags: midi, piano

[The synthesizer](http://www.vintagesynth.com/roland/d20.php) has an old floppy disc drive and a MIDI input, but I don't know how to use it with my brother's Mac.

Answer (score 5):

You can get more sounds either by [purchasing disks](http://cgi.ebay.com/Roland-D20-10-5-4-bank-set-synth-patches-/350374838893?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5193f7c26d) made specifically for the D-20 or you can get [MIDI (.mid) or Sysex (.syx) files](http://www.patchmanmusic.com/rolandd5d10d20.html) to send to your keyboard from your computer via MIDI.  You can get a copy of the [owners manual here](http://www.avtandil.narod.ru/d20e.html).  See chapter 5 of the owners manual volume 2 for instructions on how to transfer/receive data via MIDI.

Comment: i would vote you up but i can't yet thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can buy soundbanks for the Roland D20. For example, try [this site](http://www.patchmanmusic.com/rolandd5d10d20.html). It also includes instructions for how to load them (you don't use the floppy drive, you send them via MIDI from your PC).